# Cannot import module with PyCharm, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, module, pycharm

PyCharm 2018.1.3 pro / Python 3.6.1 / Module: neo4j-driver 1.5.3

The strange thing is that if I trying to import neo4j.v1 using script editor in PyCharm and run it I'm getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/experiment/Cypher.py",
>   line 1, in **from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase** ModuleNotFoundError: **No
>   module named 'neo4j'**
>   Process finished with exit code 1

But this script works just fine if I call it using Windows PowerShell environment using simple command prompt:

```
> python C:/experiment/Cypher.py
```

So, I think that something is wrong with settings or with PyCharm. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pycharm,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of  Available packages. Then search for `neo4j` python package.

Then click on Install package to install the package.

Comment: @Євген Євтушенко: Is this you are expecting ?

Comment: Now module is installed correctly and everything runs fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`neo4j.v1` is not a default python module, it is not automatically installed when you install python.

To install `neo4j.v1` Follow the instructions [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/).

Its possible to install it directly from pycharm, as other answers have pointed out, but its better to download from the official source to make sure all related dependencies and packages are properly installed.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that if I'm installing module using 'pip install ...' and the process is successful, I don't need to do anything else. But I was  wrong. And I need to install new module in project interpreter settings.